# Trying to HTTP-POST to GCM from Java

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a HTTP-POST to the Google Cloud Messaging service. I have setup the correct keys, and everything is working when I use a php script for sending push notifications to my cellphone.

But my Java httpPost only returns a 401 response. I have followed the instructions given at [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error) but I'm still getting the annoying 401. Am I assigning the header fields wrong?

My Code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

    public class Server {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          String url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);


            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id=", "MY_DEVICE_GSM_REG_ID"));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data=", "Type=value,Lat=58.365547,Long=8.613235,Comment=value"));

            httppost.setHeader("Authorization",
                    "key=MY_API_AUTH_FROM_GOOGLE_API_CONSOLE_BROWSER_TOKEN");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters, "UTF-8"));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " 
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Pretty old post, but do you realize that you have two HttpPost objecte, and you are setting the API key on the one and the payload on the other, then send the one without the API key ?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the Authorization header correctly. There is probably a problem with your API Key.

You do have a problem in your registration ID and payload (which is not related to the 401 error).

This is wrong :

```
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id=", "MY_DEVICE_GSM_REG_ID"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data=", "Type=value,Lat=58.365547,Long=8.613235,Comment=value"));
```

You should remove the `=` from the key and each payload parameter should start with `data.`. Therefore you should have:

```
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id", "MY_DEVICE_GSM_REG_ID"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.Type", "value"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.Lat", "58.365547"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.Long", "8.613235"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.Comment", "value"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the same key as I'm using in (a separate, php script. The script works just fine, using a "browser" API KEY. I believe this is the same KEY I should use for the HTTP POST in my Java Program as well? Any clue to how I could go about debugging this?

Comment: @iNzzane If this key works, perhaps you are deploying the java code  in a different server than the PHP script that works. Perhaps you defined some domain restrictions for your browser key.

Comment: I actually tried to run the program as a .jar on the same server as the script runs, to rule out local problems. Still the same error, probably have to try the JSON way.